# Нужно ли тире перед "и"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Он нажал другую кнопку, и опять ничего.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Он нажал другую кнопку, и опять ничего.

(2) Он нажал другую кнопку —  и опять ничего.

Тире в сложносочиненном предложении является **неосновным** знаком и ставится при наличии **паузы** между простыми предложениями.

Выбор знака также зависит от контекста. В данном случае тире может подчеркнуть **напряженность ситуации**, когда необходимы быстрые действия.